# Session Not working in Generic Handler .ashx in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, session, ashx

I have created .ashx which implemented IRequiresSessionState, so I can create session variables in that ashx, it worked in IE, but doesn't work in Firefox.
When access this session variable from other pages it's NULL.

any idea? thx.

Comment: Use a http proxy tool to tell what's different in the calls from each browser.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't allow cookies in Firefox. Check that! If you don't want to enable cookies, enable the cookieless session.

Comment: I checked firefox tools->option->private  the cookie is enabled still not working.

but cookieless did sovle the problem.

Comment: @user294720 would mean [Me like COOKIE!!!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_Monster) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make cookies enabled in web.config

```
<system.web>
<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```