# login from external site using ASHX handler

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, ashx

I have an ASP.NET site which requires a login to get access to the rest of the site. Login information is stored in database and accessed through a service.

The business have asked to be able to login from an external site. I added a Generic Handler (.ashx) to my project which takes username & password input, verifies the credentials, and then if they are valid stores the credentials in the session using IRequiredSessionState interface. It then gives a URL of the entry point to the application to the client.

The client (a plain old HTML page using jquery to .post()) then takes the response and redirects to this URL.

Well, this seems to work great and exactly what I needed. I figured that I could avoid having to generate a token and pass it around in the querystring by doing this, since the handler and site both share the same session. But the problem now is when I tried a test by putting the Login HTML page on a co-workers computer (eg external to hosting in my application) - it doesn't work. The session is added correctly in the ASHX handler, but in the Page_Load of the entry point, that session value is gone..

Is it possible to do what I am doing? Why is session forgot immediately like this? I would think it would be the same as logging in from the log-in page and redirecting from there (it's the same application & the same session..)

Thanks!

Comment: I had once the same issue (the session doesn't exist on page-load). I solved it by using an .aspx page instead of .ashx. Ugly solution though.

Comment: Thanks @bcolin. So you just turned your ashx into an aspx, and added WebMethods that you used instead?

Comment: not really WebMethods. In the aspx page_load, I check the credentials, set the user session, then redirect to the "home page" of my application. Then, the session exist in the home page page_load

Comment: I need to have the login portion on an external site though. So I will try this with WebMethod (so I can jquery .post()).

Comment: you should also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729825/session-not-working-in-generic-handler-ashx-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: Make sure redirect is not happening in new tab. Open in new window or tab may generate new Session Id

Comment: @Devesh I'm using window.location.replace